# Qt: Using stylesheets to change position of QDockWidget buttons

Tags: qt

I am creating a GUI using Qt. I use stylesheets to change the positions of close-button and float-button to the left side of the titlebars of DockWidgets in Mac OS X. My code looks like this:

```
QString macOSXButtonStyle = "";
#ifdef MACOSX
  macOSXButtonStyle = "QDockWidget::close-button, QDockWidget::float-button { subcontrol-position: left; } QDockWidget::close-button { left: 4px; } QDockWidget::float-button { left: 20px; }";
#endif

activeDockWidget->setStyleSheet(macOSXButtonStyle);
```

Repositioning does work. But the buttons appear smaller than before:

Before:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cargath at www.informatik.uni-bremen.de](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/~cargath/buttons_before.png))</sub>

After:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cargath at www.informatik.uni-bremen.de](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/~cargath/buttons_after.png))</sub>

I tried resizing them with different combinations of icon-size, size, width and height, but nothing seems to work. Any idea what's causing the problem / how i could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Styling a default QDockWidget with your style doesn't seem to have any effect on icon size under Win 7 or Ubuntu 10.14, using Qt4.7.

Looking closely at the before and after pictures, the difference seems to be in height - the icons have the same baseline, and the toolbar is the same height.  If explicitly changing the height hasn't worked, I wonder if some vertical padding might have been introduced somewhere? Is there any other Mac-specific styling in the app?

You could try explicitly setting padding: 0 in that style.  Zero should be the default, so this many not change anything.

Comment: I tried experimenting with padding already, but it didn't work. I've now just created a new style which inherits from the QTMac-Theme as a workaround. I was able to change the size of the buttons there. Not an elegant solution, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation, and I was able to restore the icons size by adding

```
QDockWidget
{
    icon-size: 20px;
}
```

(Tested with both Qt 4.7 and Qt 4.8.)